# Traverse HTMLDOM table with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, dom

I have a HTML table something like this:

```
<table class="Example">

<tr>

<th>Header1</th>
<td>Value1></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Header2</th>
<td>Value2></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

I want to find the `<th>` equal to "Header2" and then return the corresponding `<td>`, i.e. "Value2", which is inside the same `<tr>` .

I know I can easily use the index number, e.g. `getElementsByTagName("td")(1)` to find this value, but this is not feasible since each page may have the rows jumbled up.

I've tried doing this varying ways with no success. Hopefully, the following code indicates what I'm trying to do:

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Sub WebSearch()

Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
Dim html As IHTMLDocument
Dim Example As IHTMLElement
Dim TableRows As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TableRow As IHTMLElement
Dim RowChildren As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim RowChild As IHTMLElement
Dim TableHeader As IHTMLElement
Dim TableData As IHTMLElement

URL = "https://..."

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate URL

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

HWNDSrc = IE.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set html = IE.document

On Error Resume Next
Set Example = html.getElementsByClassName("Example")(0)

'''''''' Trying to get Result
Set TableRows = Example.Children

For Each TableRow In TableRows

    Set RowChildren = TableRow.Children

        For Each RowChild In RowChildren

            Set TableHeader = RowChild.getElementsByTagName("th")(0)
            Set TableData = TableHeader.NextSibling

            If TableHeader.innerText = "Header2" Then MsgBox TableData.innerText

        Next

Next

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this line `Set TableHeader = RowChild.getElementsByTagName("th")(0)` won't work because RowChild is in fact the `TH` element and does not have within it any `TH` elements. You could simply have `If RowChildren(0).innerText = "Header2" Then MsgBox RowChildren(1).innerText` instead of iterating through the RowChildren.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you put me on the right track and I managed to solve it! I did what you said and also changed Set TableRows = Example.Children to Set TableRows = Example.Rows.